# How to get JSON body as is in java?

Tags: java, json, spring

I am trying to get the JSON input with field names in double quotes. But when I tried to print in the screen, the double quotes are missing. I need this for input to a PL/SQL CLOB.

Here is my code:

```java
@POST
@Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Path("exportAssortmentTest")
public Response exportAssortmentTest(@Context HttpHeaders headers, Map<String, Object> request) {
    if (request == null) {
        //until I find a better solution
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)                            
            .cacheControl(null)
            .build();
    }
    
    String pojoJson = request.toString();
    System.out.println("JSON: " + pojoJson);
    String jsonResponse = RSEStringUtils.EMPTY;
    
    return Response.ok(jsonResponse, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .cacheControl(null)
        .build();
}
```

The JSON String contains fields without double quotes:

```
assortLabel=WOMENS /APPAREL 2023 H1, requestType=_2
```

This is what I would like to have:

```
"assortLabel":"WOMENS /APPAREL 2023 H1", 
"requestType": 2
```

Comment: thats because you are using the default implementation of toString(). If you want your string to look like a JSON, use a json parser to parse your object as a JSON string.

Comment: At the moment it appears the the problem is in Java before you get to try to persist any data in a database so the database is incidental and irrelevant to this problem so I have removed those tags. If it is relevant to the question then please [edit] your question and provide a [MRE] which explains how it is relevant and include: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your table; the SQL statement for inserting the data into that table; the issue/error with the SQL; and the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned in a comment, you should use a proper JSON marshalling/unmarshalling library, like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

### Add Jackson Databind Module as a Dependency

We will use the [jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki) module in this example. In Maven you can declare it as a dependency like this:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

### Use ObjectMapper to Serialize Your POJOs into JSON String

Next, we leverage the [ObjectMapper](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/latest/index.html) to serialize the POJO into a proper JSON String.

Here is a very simple POJO for demonstrative purposes:

```java
class User {
    private String name;
    private String email;

    public User(String name, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

We'll serialize an instance of this `User` class into a JSON String with double quoted fields:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

// ...
final var user = new User("John Doe", "john@doe.com");

// Since in your example your request was a Map<String, Object>:
final var userAsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

userAsMap.put("name", user.getName());
userAsMap.put("email", user.getEmail());

try {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final var json = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
    final var jsonFromMap = mapper.writeValueAsString(userAsMap);

    // Both JSON Strings should be identical    
    System.out.println(json);
    System.out.println(jsonFromMap);
} catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

**Results:**

```
{"name":"John Doe","email":"john@doe.com"}
{"name":"John Doe","email":"john@doe.com"}
```

Please refer the official documentation linked above for more fine-grained features and use cases, since it was an over-simplified example. Hope it will help.